# Is it safe to delete Java folders from C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java

Tags: windows-7, java, jdk, jre

I am using a Windows 7 64-bit PC.
I have many folders in `C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java` with names of older Java versions like:

- `jdk1.7.0_21_x64`
- `jre1.7.0_45`
- `jre1.7.0_25`

These folders contain `.msi` and `.cab` files. I have uninstalled all older versions of Java but these folders are still in that location.

Do I need those? Or is it safe to delete?

Comment: Rename them, if nothing complains after a week, delete them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if you've already uninstalled them, this is safe to do.

Also, you may find Oracle's [Java Uninstall Tool](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/uninstaller_toolinfo.xml) helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the [this bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7158412), I removed the files in `C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java` after installation. Java continued to work as it should. It became impossible to remove, using Add/Remove Programs, any version whose files I had deleted.

It seems that these files are only kept around for uninstallation. [Java Uninstall Tool](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/uninstaller_toolinfo.xml) mentioned in Jason's answer probably alleviates the need to keep those files around.

Answer (score 0):

**Recommend to nuke the folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java`**

There were 12 different versions of java in mine, from 1.6.26 to 1.8.31.

All these java versions are obsolete and past end-of-life. They have extremely serious unpatched security vulnerabilities. Better nuke them to orbit.

They were most likely installed by some software that tried to embed or auto-install java half-assedly. They will never get upgraded.

The java **un**installation tool suggested in the top answer is long dead https://www.java.com/en/download/uninstallapplet.jsp. It's a java applet, browsers have been totally blocking java for years due to recurring security issues. You can try opening in Internet Explorer but it should be broken.